# TO-3 Transistor replacement needed that does not protrude through the chassis

Tags: transistors, linear

I have a linear power supply that uses two 2N3771G. They are TO-3 style, and are exposed outside the chassis, on the heatsink.

I need to move this power supply into a new chassis, for commercial reasons.

I'm hoping to find a replacement transistor that can mount inside the new chassis, but not stick out through it. The new chassis will have heatsinks exposed on the outside.

Here are the specs of the 2N3771G:

\$V_{CEO}\$ = 40V max
\$I_C\$ = 30A max
\$h_{FE}\$ = 15 min
\$h_{FE}\$ = 60 max

How can I find a substitute?

Comment: How much power are these transistors burning?

Comment: @ThePhoton - Wood is burned, not power. Power is consumed.

Comment: @stevenvh, in engineering, "burn" also has the meaning of "turn to heat."  Some words have multiple meanings.

Comment: @markrages - steam train engineering? :-)

Comment: @markrages: what if the power is converted to light, or motion? Is it also burnt then? just curious

Comment: Don't disrespect the stream train engineers, they invented mechanical engineering.

Comment: @markrages - Oh, I know! They're the origin of the word engineer. And they burned a lot of coal.

Comment: @FedericoRusso, it would be a stretch to use it in any other way then heat but I think most would not jump down your throat. I think waste in an unimportant way might be a good fit. The implication to me is that burn is turn to heat. Meta question time? ;)

Comment: >> How much power? I'm not sure. I'm trying to place 2 linear power supplies into one chassis, with one AC input. Right now, each PSU has 2 of these transistors exposed through the heatsink. From a chassis perspective, I'd prefer to mount a transistor inside the chassis, and have heatsinks on the outside, so I can drop the requirement of 4 holes through which the transistors protrude, and I can use a "continuous" heatsink, instead of one that can accomodate the transformers.

Answer (score 1):

You could look for a straight replacement in one of the plastic cases like TO-3P or TO-247, such as STW3040 (which is "not recommended for new design") or BUF420AW (surprisingly expensive.)

A better choice might be a pair of TO-220 transistors, but you need to look at the surrounding circuit first.  Bipolar transistors can't be simply paralleled, but need some emitter resistors to ensure they share current properly and don't run away thermally.

For linear operation, most of the important design considerations will be expressed by the safe operating area graph (assuming you use the same size of heat sink, so thermal considerations are OK):

[image]

You are considering DC operation, which is the lowest line on the curve.   You need to make sure the operation stays within that lower line.  To just do a part substitution without circuit analysis, you can compare the SOA curve of the replacement with the original part, and make sure the original curve fits under the replacement curve.

Comment: +1 for mentioning TO-3P and TO-247. This info, combined with a manufacturer's online parametric search tool, will yield good results.

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/BUW48/BUW48-ND/1037781

Can someone tell me if this is the right one? (I'm not an electrical engineer, and am a little over my head)

Comment: You need to understand a fair amount of electronics to do this substitution successfully.  Maybe you would do better to mount the TO-3 on a smaller heatsink internally, then connect the heatsink to the large external heatsink.  Then no circuit changes are required and you can continue to use the inexpensive TO-3 part.